# filling nan values with two different values

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, expandablelistview, numpy-ndarray, pandas-datareader

Some values in the`enter code here` FlightNumber column are missing. These numbers are meant to increase by 10 with each row so 10055 and 10075 need to be put in place. Fill in these missing numbers and make the column an integer column (instead of a float column). Some values in the FlightNumber column are missing. These numbers are meant to increase by 10 with each row so 10055 and 10075 need to be put in place. Fill in these missing numbers and make the column an integer column (instead of a float column). 
I tried this but not getting the correct result.

```
df['FlightNumber'].fillna(10055, inplace = True)
df['FlightNumber'].fillna(10075, inplace = True)
df[['FlightNumber']] = df[['FlightNumber']].astype(int)
df
```

Comment: your first ``fillna` will fill all missing values.. second `fillna`` is useless.

Comment: Provide sample data.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'From_To': ['LoNDon_paris', 'MAdrid_miLAN', 'londON_StockhOlm', 'Budapest_PaRis', 'Brussels_londOn'], 
 
'FlightNumber': [10045, np.nan, 10065, np.nan, 10085], 
 
'RecentDelays': [[23, 47], [], [24, 43, 87], [13], [67, 32]], 
 
'Airline': ['KLM(!)', '<Air France> (12)', '(British Airways. )', '12. Air France', '"Swiss Air"']})

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df['FlightNumber'].isna(),'FlightNumber'] = df.loc[df[df['FlightNumber'].isna()].index-1,'FlightNumber'].astype(int)+10
```

Comment: Describe your answer please